# Redefining RSpec shared examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

We repeatedly run RSpec from within a single runtime (we use this to get around the Jruby startup time problem). THis has been working fine until we started using shared_examples. If we run rspec twice with a shared_example, we get "Shared example group 'an email' already exists". How do we remove or reset the shared groups, or otherwise get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I should call`RSpec.world.reset`, though that doesn't work in practice (filed a bug for it: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-dev/issues/27). This works though:

```
RSpec.world.shared_example_groups.clear
```